# How to style a google doc in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I've been fiddling with this idea here:

http://jsfiddle.net/M68GL/9/

I have it exactly how I want it except for one thing.  The opacity of the div holding the iframe is correctly inherited by the iframe.  However, instead of it only effecting the background of the google doc, it effects the entire google doc.  I want it to only effect the background of the google doc.

This way images, text, etc will still be seen with 100% opacity.

Is there a way to do this?

Oddly enough, the seamless attribute seemed to have no effect on the behavior.

```
<div id = "outer">   <div id = "inner"></div>   <iframe scrolling="no" id="test" src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IodTYp_yaxBlgEUv_TqKK-1oTgjbmh0VTg4jjX3LjKE/pub"
></iframe> </div>
```

This effect of text over an opaque div seems to be common not only in web, but modern Operating Systems as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying the opacity to the "outer" div, which is therefore rendering everything contained within (text, images, google doc) to opacity = 0.5.

I believe your intent is to render the background of the "outer" div to have opacity of 0.5, while the iframe itself continues to have a opacity = 1.0.

This will take a bit of layering magic, as everything within the div takes on the opacity assigned by it's parent, considering opacity = 1 to be opacity = .5 as per the parent div ('outer').

There are different ways of doing it but overall my suggested method is to seperate the iframe and the opaque background you wish to use and then layer the iframe over the opaque background. I have modified the link you attached to accomplish this to some degree!

```
 <div id = "outer">
 <div id = "inner"></div></div>
    <iframe scrolling="no" id="test" src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IodTYp_yaxBlgEUv_TqKK-1oTgjbmh0VTg4jjX3LjKE/pub" >                                               
</iframe>
```

then the css

```
 #test{
border: 0;
width: 800px;
height: 8000px;
position: relative;
left: 100px;
padding:20px;
}
 #outer{
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
padding: 20px;
background: #ffffff;
opacity: .5;
width: 800px;
height: 8000px;
 }
 #inner{
position: absolute;
width: 800px;
height: 40px;
background: #ffffff;
  }
body{
background: url('http://www.arcmarks.com/arcmarks/images/grid.jpg');
}
```

Also, if you use this method I would consider containing the components in a div of their own for easier styling and manipulation as such

```
<div id="iframeWithOpaqueBackground">
 <div id = "outer">
  <div id = "inner"></div></div>
     <iframe scrolling="no" id="test"  src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IodTYp_yaxBlgEUv_TqKK-1oTgjbmh0VTg4jjX3LjKE/pub" >    
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: i see that it works, but how did you get rid of the white background of the iframe, I thought it had one by default?

Comment: why does it continue to show through in the top title - I have fiddled with it some more here - http://jsfiddle.net/ac9t2/1/

Comment: i believe the background of the iframe (in particular the google doc) was transparent I did nothing special there.... in the first fiddle I remember the divs outer and inner being set to #ffffff. And for the title question are you wanting the "Community" invisible as it was on original fiddle?